# Como modificar esta instrução para obter uma url para pt_BR?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, url-amigável

Estou trabalhando com o tema `Academy` feito pelos gringos e gostaria de saber como modificar essa instrução para conseguir substituir **`register`** por `cadastrar` e assim conseguir uma url em `pt_BR`.

```
'register' => array(
    'title' => __('Registration', 'academy'),
    'name' => 'register',
    'rule' => 'register/?',
    'rewrite' => 'index.php?register=1',
    'position' => 'top',
    'authorized' => false,
), ...
```

Será que tenho que modificar só neste ponto ou em outros pontos do tema, a chamada pode não funcionar?

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/297/101